# How to access parent component value from child component without passing it via an input?

Tags: angular

I'm making an email modal but I'm having problems actually making the `http.post` request. The problem is that `post()` is being executed in a child component which means that `this.postUrl` is undefined when the function actually runs. How can I make sure that the child component has access to `this.postUrl` without passing it to it as an input? The reason as to why I don't want to pass it with an input is that the child component is also used in other places, making the `postUrl` too specific to use as an input since it will only be used in this scenario.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-email',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/modal/templates/modal-email/modal-email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/modal/templates/modal-email/modal-email.component.css'],
  inputs: [
    'model',
    'postUrl',
    'header',
    'text'
  ],
  directives: [FormInputWithButtonComponent],
  providers: [Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class ModalEmailComponent {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {

  }

  post() {

    // this.postUrl becomes undefined, this.model is defined since it also lives in the child component
    console.log(this.postUrl, this.model);

    this._http.post(this.postUrl, {email: this.model})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.data = data,
        err => console.log(err)
      )
  }
}
```

`ModalEmailComponent` is being used like this:

```
<modal-email postUrl="localhost:3000/email"></modal-email>
```

Inside the `modal-email` lies `form-input-with-button>` component:

```
<form-input-with-button [(model)]="email" type="email" [onSubmit]="post"></form-input-with-button>
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-input-with-button',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-input-with-button/form-input-with-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-input-with-button/form-input-with-button.component.css'],
  inputs: [
    'model',
    'onSubmit' // onSubmit is what calls the post function from ModalEmailComponent
  ],
  host: {
    '(input)': 'modelChange.emit($event.target.value)'
  }
})

export class FormInputWithButtonComponent {
  @Input() model: string;
  @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}
```

`FormInputWithButtonComponent` template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model" class="form-input-with-button">
<button (click)="onSubmit()" class="form-input-button">Submit</button>
```

**EDIT:** Can you extend components? Something like:

```
export class FormInputWithButtonComponent extends ModalEmailComponent
```

When I tried it said `Cannot read property prototype of undefined` which makes me think that this is not possible.

Comment: I think inheritance is not supported yet (I may be wrong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can inject **parent component properties, values** from your **child** component without using any services or **inputs**.

First, you need to inject `Injector` from a constructor in a child component:

```
    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(public injector:Injector) {
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            let parentComponent = this.injector.get(ParentComponent);
            this.postUrl = parentComponent.
        }
    }
```

Imports

```
import {Injector} from "angular2/core";
import {OnInit} from "angular2/core";
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: This is indeed a great solution +1 !

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you to do, is to create one Service, where you would store the value of the `postUrl`, so that it would be accessible in the child. On the other hand, you can use Event Emitter, and set it as follows:

In ChildComponent:

```
onSubmit(){
  EventEmit.emit('get')    
}

EventEmit.subscribe(msg=>{
  http.post(msg)
})
```

And in the parent:

```
EventEmit.subscribe(msg=>

if (msg == 'get') EventEmit.emit(this.postUrl)

);
```

Of course, thats just pseudo code, so you would need to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Both of those solutions require too much specific logic.. But perhaps it is indeed the only way. Which doesn't make a whole lotta sense.

Comment: Creating service is pretty simple. ;)

Comment: Ofc it's easy, but that would require every `FormInputWithButtonComponent` to always have a hook to the `ModalEmailComponent` even when used elsewhere. Which is not good.

Comment: You would hook each FormInputComponent to the service, and ModalEmail to the service as well. FormInput wouldnt have direct access to the modalemailcomp